# How to start game of snake with key press event?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, event-listener

I have created a simple game of Snake using HTML 5 Canvas and JavaScript. I am nearly finished with the small project, however, I have one problem that I can't solve. On load, the game of snake automatically starts, usually resulting in a "Game Over", I would like for the player to be able to first press the direction they are wanting to go, and then the game will start. I have tried every way I can think possible to do this, mainly by using "keydown" or other similar event listeners. No matter where I put the code, nothing seems to work. Any ideas? Many thanks to anyone who takes the time out of their day to help me, it is greatly appreciated. Below, I will leave the code for the project for those wanting to help.

Snake game website: [Snake Game](https://snake.dwcreate.co.uk)

HTML/CSS:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

    var cvsW = cvs.width;
    var cvsH = cvs.height;

    var snakeW = 20;
    var snakeH = 20;

    let score = 0;

    var direction = "right";

    this.document.addEventListener("keydown", getDirection);

    function getDirection(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != "right") {
            direction = "left";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != "down") {
            direction = "up";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != "left") {
            direction = "right";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != "up") {
            direction = "down";
        }
    }

    function drawSnake(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#507786";
        ctx.fillRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#507786";
        ctx.strokeRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);
    }

    drawSnake(4, 5);

    var len = 4;
    var snake = [];

    for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        snake.push({
            x: i,
            y: 0
        });
    }

   food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsW / snakeW - 1) + 1),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsH / snakeH - 1) + 1)
    }

    function drawFood(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#507786";
        ctx.strokeRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);
    }

    function checkCollision(x,y,array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (x == array[i].x && y == array[i].y) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
            var x = snake[i].x;
            var y = snake[i].y;
            drawSnake(x, y);
        }

        drawFood(food.x, food.y);

        var snakeX = snake[0].x;
        var snakeY = snake[0].y;

        if (direction == "left") snakeX--;
        else if (direction == "up") snakeY--;
        else if (direction == "right") snakeX++;
        else if (direction == "down") snakeY++;

        if (snakeX < 0 || snakeY < 0 || snakeX >= cvsW / snakeW || snakeY >= cvsH / snakeH
            || checkCollision(snakeX,snakeY,snake)) {
            snake = null;    
            document.getElementById("gameover").innerHTML = "Game Over";
            setInterval(function(){
                location.reload();
            }, 3000);
        }

        if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
            food = {
                x : Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsW / snakeW -1) + 1),
                y : Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsH / snakeH -1) + 1)
            }
            var newHead = {
                x : snakeX,
                y : snakeY
            };
            score += 1
            document.getElementById("gameScore").innerHTML = score;
        } else {
            snake.pop();
            var newHead = {
                x : snakeX,
                y : snakeY
            };
        }

        snake.unshift(newHead);
    }

    setInterval(draw, 60);

}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
    Snake Game
</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sniglet&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #canvas {
        background-color: #8BAC0F;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }

    #snakeGroup {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #snakeTitle {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 80px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #snakePara {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #gameover {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #footerText {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
</style>

<body onkeypress="window.onload">
    <div id="snakeGroup">
        <h1 id="snakeTitle">Snake </h1>
        <p id="snakePara">Press the arrow keys ⬅️⬆️⬇️➡️ to move the snake.<br> Eat the food to score points. If the
            snake touches the walls
            or itself, its game over.<br> The game will automatically restart after 3 seconds. Happy Gaming!</p>
        <h2 id="gameover">Score: <span id="gameScore"></span></h2>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
        <h3 id="footerText">Made with ❤️ by David Winters</h3>
    </div>

    <script src="snake.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am having fun in playing your game but please make document scroll when user press arrow keys

Comment: @Ahmed, to add some constructivnes to the critics, adding e.preventDeafult(); at the end of the keyCode if cases would stop the document from scrolling when arrow keys are pressed if that's what wanted.

Comment: you can create the document with 100% dimensions, but I suggest you to do this in CSS

Answer (score 0):

It starts automatically because you call `drawSnake(4, 5)` later down the code and you have already set direction on initialization to `‘right’`

You should be able to fix this by assigning a variable like `hasStarted` to false at initialization. And then checking in the onKeydown handler whether  `hasStarted` is true or false. If it is false (the game has not started yet), `hasStarted` is set to true and then the `setInterval(draw, 60)` should be called.

```
var hasStarted = false;
var direction = “”;
this.document.addEventListener("keydown", getDirection);

function getDirection(e) {
    if (!hasStarted) {
        hasStarted = true
        switch e.keyCode {
            case 37:
                direction = "left";
                break;
            case 38:
                direction = "up";
                break;
            case 39:
                direction = "right";
                break;
            case 40:
                direction = "down";
                break;
            default:
                direction = "right";
                break;
        }
        setInterval(draw, 60);
    } else {
        if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != "right") {
            direction = "left";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != "down") {
            direction = "up";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != "left") {
            direction = "right";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != "up") {
            direction = "down";
        }
    }
}
```

Edit #1 (kudos to Mattias):
You’ll have to also remove the call to setInterval on last line of code.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Sadly, your code did not work for me but has put me on to a different train of thought on how to tackle this. When I use your code, The snake briefly flashes onto the screen, and then the game restarts and repeats. Do you have your code working with my code on your end? Again, many thanks!

Comment: You have to remember to delete the last setInterval(draw, 60); at the end of your code example. https://jsfiddle.net/nfb325uc/1/

Comment: Thank you Mattias. I forgot to mention this in my answer. I will add this tip.

Comment: NP, also noticed that the initiation of hasStarted are missing so 'var hasStarted = false;' also needs to be added.

Comment: Thank you both so much! The code works! I am very grateful for both your help!

Comment: No problem! Happy to have helped :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initiate the direction with right you can inner wrap the draw function with a check to see if direction are set.

```
...
    var direction = "";
...
```

```
...
    function draw() {
      if(direction != ""){
        ...
      }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you initialize direction as "start"-

```
var direction = "start";
```

then add this code in the draw function right after you initialize snakeX and snakeY-

> ```
>     var snakeX = snake[0].x;
>     var snakeY = snake[0].y;
>
>     if (direction == "start") 
>     {
>     snakeX =  snakeX*.0001;
>     }
> ```

Thus, the snake will initially be moving very slowly, and it will appear that the snake won't start moving unless you press "keydown".

I added the code in the code snippet.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

    var cvsW = cvs.width;
    var cvsH = cvs.height;

    var snakeW = 20;
    var snakeH = 20;

    let score = 0;

    var direction = "start";

    this.document.addEventListener("keydown", getDirection);

    function getDirection(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != "right") {
            direction = "left";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != "down") {
            direction = "up";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != "left") {
            direction = "right";
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != "up") {
            direction = "down";
        }
    }

    function drawSnake(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#507786";
        ctx.fillRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#507786";
        ctx.strokeRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);
    }

    drawSnake(4, 5);

    var len = 4;
    var snake = [];

    for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        snake.push({
            x: i,
            y: 0
        });
    }

   food = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsW / snakeW - 1) + 1),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsH / snakeH - 1) + 1)
    }

    function drawFood(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#507786";
        ctx.strokeRect(x * snakeW, y * snakeH, snakeW, snakeH);
    }

    function checkCollision(x,y,array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (x == array[i].x && y == array[i].y) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
            var x = snake[i].x;
            var y = snake[i].y;
            drawSnake(x, y);
        }

        drawFood(food.x, food.y);

        var snakeX = snake[0].x;
        var snakeY = snake[0].y;
        
        
         if (direction == "start") 
          {
          snakeX =  snakeX*.0001;
          }

        if (direction == "left") snakeX--;
        else if (direction == "up") snakeY--;
        else if (direction == "right") snakeX++;
        else if (direction == "down") snakeY++;

        if (snakeX < 0 || snakeY < 0 || snakeX >= cvsW / snakeW || snakeY >= cvsH / snakeH
            || checkCollision(snakeX,snakeY,snake)) {
            snake = null;    
            document.getElementById("gameover").innerHTML = "Game Over";
            setInterval(function(){
                location.reload();
            }, 3000);
        }

        if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
            food = {
                x : Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsW / snakeW -1) + 1),
                y : Math.floor(Math.random() * (cvsH / snakeH -1) + 1)
            }
            var newHead = {
                x : snakeX,
                y : snakeY
            };
            score += 1
            document.getElementById("gameScore").innerHTML = score;
        } else {
            snake.pop();
            var newHead = {
                x : snakeX,
                y : snakeY
            };
        }

        snake.unshift(newHead);
    }

    setInterval(draw, 60);

}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
    Snake Game
</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sniglet&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #canvas {
        background-color: #8BAC0F;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }

    #snakeGroup {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #snakeTitle {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 80px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #snakePara {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #gameover {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #footerText {
        font-family: 'Sniglet', cursive;
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
</style>

<body onkeypress="window.onload">
    <div id="snakeGroup">
        <h1 id="snakeTitle">Snake </h1>
        <p id="snakePara">Press the arrow keys ⬅️⬆️⬇️➡️ to move the snake.<br> Eat the food to score points. If the
            snake touches the walls
            or itself, its game over.<br> The game will automatically restart after 3 seconds. Happy Gaming!</p>
        <h2 id="gameover">Score: <span id="gameScore"></span></h2>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
        <h3 id="footerText">Made with ❤️ by David Winters</h3>
    </div>

    <script src="snake.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```